# How to Join Two MongoDB Collections on the Same Field Name with the same value?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections in my MongoDB Database that I want to join then on the same field value when I search for a number. Here is my collections structure:

First collection's name is users:

```
{
user_id : "1234",
phone_number: "+9600000000000"
}
```

Second collection's name is users_info:

```
{
name : "John Smith",
phone_number: "+9600000000000",
age: "45",
address: "DC"
}
```

I want to create a query joining those two collections where `phone_number` is equal to a value. The result to be similar to the following:

```
{
user_id : "1234",
name :"John Smith",
phone_number: "+9600000000000",
age: "45",
address: "DC"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "phone_number": "+9600000000000"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users_info",
      "localField": "phone_number",
      "foreignField": "phone_number",
      "as": "user_info",
      "pipeline": [
        {"$unset": "_id"}
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": {
      "$mergeObjects": [
        "$$ROOT",
        {"$first": "$user_info"}
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": ["_id", "user_info"]
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5vhg2KPevrW).

If your MongoDB server version is before 4.2 when `"$unset"` became available, you can use `"$project"` instead, like this.

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "phone_number": "+9600000000000"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users_info",
      "localField": "phone_number",
      "foreignField": "phone_number",
      "as": "user_info",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": {
      "$mergeObjects": [
        "$$ROOT",
        {"$first": "$user_info"}
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "user_info": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U6yamRtsLtL).

Comment: the only problem is the $unset is not recognizable on my local machine. I think it works on Mongo Atlas. Thanks.

Comment: @Shwan  [`"$unset"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/ "Link to MongoDB manual -->") was added in MongoDB version 4.2.  You must have an old version of MongoDB.  You can use `"$project"` if `"$unset"` is unavailable.  See updated answer.

Comment: @Shwan Does my updated answer work for you?

Comment: your answer was correct. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Shwan If the answer is helpful, it's useful to other readers to upvote and/or accept the answer.